# How to filter a list in-place with Kotlin?

Tags: list, kotlin, filtering

In Java I can remove items from a list with this code:

```
private void filterList(List<Item> items) {
    Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        if (checkItem(iterator.next())) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

How to make the same in Kotlin (i.e. remove some items in a `List` without re-creation)?

Comment: just copy this code to kotlin file, IDE automatically do it for you.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Just use [`.retainAll { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/retain-all.html) or [`.removeAll { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/remove-all.html), both accepting a predicate, to filter it in-place:

```
items.retainAll { shouldRetain(it) }
```

```
items.removeAll { shouldRemove(it) }
```

Note that `items` should be a `MutableList<T>` for that, not just `List<T>`, which is a read-only list in Kotlin and thus does not expose any mutating functions (see: [*Collections*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections.html#collections) in the language reference).

<sub>By the way, these two function are implemented efficiently for lists that support random access: then the list is not compacted after each item is removed (*O(n<sup>2</sup>)* time worst-case), and instead the items are moved within the list as it is processed, giving *O(n)* time.</sub>

---

And if you don't want to modify the original list, you can produce a separate collection with only the items you want to retain using [`.filter { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html) or [`.filterNot { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-not.html), this will work for read-only `List<T>` as well:

```
val filtered = items.filter { shouldRetain(it) }
```

```
val filtered = items.filterNot { shouldRemove(it) }
```

Comment: I would've been stunned if there wasn't a function for this. The standard library is amazing.

Comment: Did you mean `removeAll`? Because in the question an item is removed when the predicate *passes*.

Comment: @Ilya, thanks, it's just the name `checkItem` confused me. Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Kotlin has a lot of neat built-in functions. You can try to use `filter` here.

```
val filteredItems = items.filter { checkItem(it) }
```

Unfortunately, it will recreate the list. This API was designed on purpose to avoid extra mutability.

But if you still want to proceed with a MutableList use `retainAll` method

```
items.retainAll { checkItem(it) }
```

Answer (score 2):

This will remove even numbers from the list 1-9, and prints `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]`

```
var myLists = mutableListOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
myLists.removeAll{ it % 2 == 0 }
println(myLists)
```

This will retain even numbers and remove others from the list 1-9, and prints `[2, 4, 6, 8]`

```
myLists = mutableListOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
myLists.retainAll{ it % 2 == 0 }
println(myLists)
```

Try them in https://play.kotlinlang.org/