# How to filter a Mutable Map in place in Kotlin

Tags: dictionary, kotlin

I would like to remove items from a `MutableMap`, similar to `filter`.
In list I can use `removeAll { }` and `retainAll { }`
(see this question: [How to filter a list in-place with Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44674532/how-to-filter-a-list-in-place-with-kotlin)).

Is there something similar for Mutable Maps?

EDIT:

I found that `entries` property of Map has those methods.

Comment: So, why wouldn't use a filter - `val newMap: HashMap<String, Any> = oldMap.filter { entry -> /* some condition */ }` ?

Comment: Old map is a class member so I want to keep it val (final)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One option would be to operate on the map's [`keys: MutableSet<K>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-map/keys.html), where you can use `removeAll { ... }` or `retainAll { ... }` just as you would with a list:

```
val m = mutableMapOf(1 to "a", 2 to "b")
m.keys.removeAll { it % 2 == 0 }
println(m) // {1=a}
```

[<sup>(runnable sample)</sup>](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4zLVJDIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJmb2xkZWRCdXR0b24iOnRydWUsInJlYWRPbmx5IjpmYWxzZSwiY29kZSI6ImZ1biBtYWluKCkge1xuICAgIHZhbCBtID0gbXV0YWJsZU1hcE9mKDEgdG8gXCJhXCIsIDIgdG8gXCJiXCIpXG4gICAgbS5rZXlzLnJlbW92ZUlmIHsgaXQgJSAyID09IDAgfVxuICAgIHByaW50bG4obSlcbn0ifQ==)

If just keys are not enough for the predicate, you can simply do the same with the map's entry set, [`entries: MutableSet<MutableEntry<K, V>>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-map/entries.html)

```
val m = mutableMapOf(1 to "a", 2 to "b", 3 to "c")
m.entries.retainAll { it.key < 3 }
m.entries.removeAll { (k, v) -> k == 1 && v == "a" }
println(m) // {2=b}
```

[<sup>(runnable sample)</sup>](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4zLVJDIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJmb2xkZWRCdXR0b24iOnRydWUsInJlYWRPbmx5IjpmYWxzZSwiY29kZSI6ImZ1biBtYWluKCkge1xuICAgIHZhbCBtID0gbXV0YWJsZU1hcE9mKDEgdG8gXCJhXCIsIDIgdG8gXCJiXCIsIDMgdG8gXCJjXCIpXG4gICAgbS5lbnRyaWVzLnJldGFpbkFsbCB7IChrLCBfKSAtPiBrIDwgMyB9XG4gICAgbS5lbnRyaWVzLnJlbW92ZUFsbCB7IChrLCB2KSAtPiBrID09IDEgJiYgdiA9PSBcImFcIiB9XG4gICAgcHJpbnRsbihtKVxufSJ9)